# Код через volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Пришёл на новый проект. Все системы в докерах. Но используют докеры странно. Оказалось, что здесь не происходит сборки контейнеров. Т.е. весь код подсовывается через volume внутрь контейнера. Выглядит максимально странным. Ребята сказали, что они так ускорили сборку (фактически её нет, сборки).

С моей стороны претензия к этому:

- я бы хотел использовать оркестратор, чтобы избавить себя от возни с конкретными виртуалками и отдать это на откуп кубернетесу. При таком подходе с volume мы не сможем нормально пользоваться kubernetes.

Костыль, но противопоставить этому я могу немногое. Вопрос: какие аргументы за и против прокидывания кода через volume?

Comment: аргументы за и против "распространения кода через volume" или "использования оркестратора, например куба"?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten я про volume говорю

Comment: "За" - локально действительно может быть быстро. "Против" - непереносимо за пределы локальной среды. Точнее переносимо, но уже с намного большими сложностями, чем обычный контейнер.

Comment: Вопроса нет в "вопросе".  У нас на "производстве" применяется докер для сборки в AWS ECR/ECS (docker build) и для упаковки для AWS Lambda вот тут то мы тоже используем (docker --volume) для монтирования исходника и для выгрузки на хост готового пакета, в докере подтягиваются зависимости  (проекты на Python, Node.js, golang).

Comment: @Hellseher не очень понятно. Могли бы подробнее написать. С AWS не работал. Знаю, есть отличия от виртуалок гугла и яндекса.

Comment: Что мешает при билде упаковывать код в другой контейнер и подключать volume из него? Зато локально всё прекрасно летает.